# How to translate api documentation. Only one method provided

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, api

I am new to creating apis for web applications. I find it really awesome. I am trying to build an application using scripture from https://bibles.org/pages/api. I'm trying to build it using angular and asp.net web api. I am not find any of the examples helpful at all.

So...I can go to this website https://bibles.org/v2/chapters/eng-KJVA:Acts.8.js in my web browser and put in my user name: which is my api key...and the password is ignored...so it doesn't matter what i put in and then it works.

When I call this same website in angular it does not work...Can't figure out where to put as my api key. It returns as unauthorized each time. Any ideas?

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCon', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://bibles.org/v2/chapters/eng-KJVA:Acts.8.js", {
        headers: {
            "username": "MYKEY!!!!",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }
        ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.book = data.Book;
            $scope.chapter = data.Chapter;
            $scope.output = data.Output;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";

        });

});
```

RETURNS UNAUTHORIZED. CAN'T FIND OUT HOW TO DO THIS READING THROUGH THE API DOCUMENTATION. ANY TRICKS?

Comment: I am emailing them...but I hoped to get advice from an experienced programmer. I recently watched a video about integrating apis to WordPress and using Angular and he mentioned how much of a horror it was to work with api documentation. I guess I'm seeing that now.

Comment: It might be the way you send headers. Try testing the same request with `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You just have to change it to:

```
$http.get('https://{token}:X@bibles.org/v2/versions/eng-GNTD.js', {...
```

Comment: I'll have to check that out sometime soon. It was returning that CORs wasn't enabled on the database and so I couldn't use through an http call on angular. I really want to learn more about apis soon. Thanks for your comment.